# Number of integers between 20000 and 70000 where digits 1,2,3 appear at least once

Tags: combinatorics

I've been struggling with this particular question regarding combinatorics... "How many integers are between 20000 and 70000 (including both) where digits 1,2,3 appear at least once?"

I've tried to count in an opposite way (count those where none of these digits appear, where appears exactly one of them - once, and where appears exactly two of them - once). However this is getting too difficult and the result summation is giving a negative number (so I really messed up with this). I can't think about another method to get to the answer.

Comment: Your approach, inclusion-exclusion, sounds optimal.  Should work. If you edit to include your calculation, maybe people can spot where it goes wrong.

Comment: Possibly worth considering $20000-29999, 30000-39999, 40000-69999$ separately

Answer (score 1):

As a starter (cf. *Henry*'s hint in the comment). For the range $40000,\ldots,49999$, there are

- $4$ ways to pick one of the last four places for a digit not among 1,2,3; then $10-3=7$ ways to pick a digit for that place; and $3!=6$ to arrange the 1,2,3 digits among the other three places. This gives us $168$ numbers
- $3$ ways to pick one of 1,2,3 as occuring twice; ${4\choose 2}=6$ ways to pick the places for this twice occuring digit; $2$ ways to arrange the other two digits in the other two places. This gives us $36$ numbers

Thus there are $168+36=204$ such numbers in the range $40000,\ldots,49999$.

Comment: Well, I got that numbers in my solution... we should use the same idea for numbers in 50000...59999 and 60000...69999. My only problem is really the 30000...39999 case (20000...29999 in analogous to this).

Comment: @kapalasd3  As lulu suggested, you should include your calculations in your question so that we can provide you with feedback.